# Простой вопрос по верстке по fontawesome

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, шрифты, fontawesome

У меня есть гамбургер он выводится, все ок. fontawesome работает. Пишу:

```
.sect1h2::before{
      color:#e3b000;
      content:"\1003";
}
```

Выводится квадратик.
При попытке вывест гамбургер (f0c9) - тоже квадратик
Что я деляю не так???

Comment: подключили неправильно библиотеку FA

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css"> там первые удалились в ссылке до слешей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.symbol:before {
  content: '\f0c9';
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/610c2bddb2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="symbol"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: С этого полегчало) Спасибо. Только код 1003 все-равно не выводится(((

Comment: @Yevgeniy что-то я не помню символов 1003 используемых, особенно в FA =) О каком символе речь?

Comment: Извиняюсь, опечатался. Все заработало. Большое спасибо!